# Apache SSL renewal keeps using old certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I have a website using Apache that runs on a GCP VM instance with a Google load balancer.
In total, I have 3 servers

I have changed the SSL certificate in the Google load balance configuration.

What I have done so far to check are

1. using gcloud command `gcloud compute target-https-proxies list` to check if the latest SSL was installed or not
2. Running gcloud command `gcloud compute target-https-proxies update PROXY_NAME --url-map=URL_MAP` to update with latest proxy configuration

And everything looks good, but from the browser, I still can see that the website uses an old SSL certificate.

I also tried to use another browser or the [online tool](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) that [John Hanley](https://serverfault.com/users/437769/john-hanley) suggested, but still, it shows as the old certificate.

any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Browsers sometimes cache certificates. Use a different browser and reverify. You can also online tools such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ Edit your question as it is not clear what is serving your certificate - load balancer or Apache.

Comment: since it's running under the load balancer so I guess there's something with the Google load balancer, thanks for pointed that hint @JohnHanley, do you think I need to restart the server?

Comment: Edit your question with details on the front end(s) configured with certificates.